# Laravel4 Eloquent compound WHERE in overloaded newQuery() model method?

Tags: model, laravel-4, scope, eloquent

I needed to make a default global scope for a model [using the `newQuery()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812826/default-scope-for-eloquent-models).

The Laravel docs [say that it's possible](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres) in Eloquent to use an anonymous function to group WHERE conditions:

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('name', '=', 'John')
        ->orWhere(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                  ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
        })
        ->get();
```

But I'm running into something strange when trying that in an overloaded `newQuery()` method. For example, let's say I want to do this:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    public function newQuery()
    {
        return parent::newQuery()->where(function($query) {
            $query->where('foreign_id', MyClass::$id)->orWhere('role', 'admin');
        });
    }
```

I get a 502 Bad Gateway error! The only way I could figure out how to do a compound WHERE in that method is by doing a raw query:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    public function newQuery()
    {
        return parent::newQuery()
            ->whereRaw('(foreign_id = ? or role = ?)')
            ->setBindings( array( MyClass::$id, 'admin' ) );
    }
```

Does anyone know why that could be happening with Eloquent? [It looks like someone else had a slightly different issue with Eloquent in that same method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280813/laravel-wherehas-not-working-in-newquery), but there was no definitive answer.

Comment: Is it older version of the framework that you need to do it this way? Global scopes are meant for this, not `newQuery`.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_ thanks for the info! I think at the time I was searching for how to do it properly, I didn't know the term "global scope" in regards to filtering regards by default. Going to check this out.

Comment: Let's have it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need global scope for this.

Here's a basic example (for more info browser `SoftDeletingScope` and `SoftDeletingTrait` that come with the framework):

```
// Model
class PopularUser extends User {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new PopularUserScope);
    }
}

// Scope
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;

class PopularUserScope implements ScopeInterface {

    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $builder->where('votes', '>', 100)
                ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
    }

    public function remove(Builder $builder) { // you don't need this in your case }
}
```